# Google Play Games Services - Maximum number of players with AutoMatch

Tags: ios, real-time, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am creating a realtime multiplayer game on iOS with Google Play Games Services. I have things working fine but the only problem is, it does not find any player if I set minimum number of players for the room greater than 7. If I set it to 7, it works fine. Over 7, it does not show any player while match making. Is there a restriction on maximum number of players for a realtime match in Google Play Games Services? My game required a total of 16 players in 8 vs. 8 team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of players is currently limited to 8 in a realtime multiplayer room. (Source: https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer)

The limit includes the player initiating the match which means that at most 7 additional players can be added to the room.